# Creating models based on what's in db/schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have this in my `db/schema.rb`:

```
create_table "bank", :force => true do |t|
  t.string    "name",       :null => false
  t.string    "identifier", :null => false
  t.timestamp "created_at", :null => false
  t.timestamp "updated_at", :null => false
end
```

Is there an easy way for me to create a model based on this? I would hate to have to manually type

```
rails generate model Bank name:string identifier:string
```

because I have about 40 tables in my database, many having many more columns than this.

Is this possible?

Comment: Just out of interest... how did you get the database schema without running some variant of `rails generate`?

Comment: Good question. I used `rake schema:db:dump`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to backtrace to getting models & migrations out of an existing `db/schema.rb`?

`schema.rb` should be the result of your migrations, and you really don't need do do anything for the models, as all you need to do is create a class that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`.

In other words, specifying columns in `rails generate model Bank name:string identifier:string` simply creates the migration for you, there's no notion of these attributes in the model file.

Comment: Ahhh! That makes so much sense. Knowing what I already knew, I should have been able to put that together myself. Thanks.